# How to calculate the actual COP of a compression for a given outdoor temperature?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, energy-efficiency

Given a chiller having a nominal COP value, how can we compute the actual COP for a given outdoor temperature.
In this regard, is there any difference between compression chillers and absorption chillers.

Comment: Cooling power / input power but be consistent with units.

Comment: do you mean how do we calculate it?  That's hard, everything changes as we change input parameters.  How to measure it is easy.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the COP taking into consideration the outdoor temperature, since the COP changes with the outdoor temperature. When a chiller is designed, there is a designed COP for it. How this COP varies with the outdoor temperature? is there an equation or a method to calculate this?

Comment: These are two completely different questions: 1) how to determine COP at a specific operating point given nominal COP, and 2) differences between compression and absorption chillers. I recommend asking them as separate questions. Regarding the former, the query you need is "performance curve."